# Transform curl into pycurl

Tags: curl, pycurl

can anyone help me to transform the following curl(from IBM watson speech to text) into pycurl please:

curl -X POST -u {username}:{password} \

--header "Content-Type: audio/flac" \

--data-binary @{path_to_file}audio-file.flac \

"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"

Comment: If you are using python, why not just use the WDC SDK? It's available on pip. https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/tree/master

Comment: i am using jupyter on windows

Comment: It works on Jupyter.